# Write large amount or rows to a mssql database using c#

Tags: c#, .net, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm having problems with a code that commits a large number of data rows to a database (sql 2008 R2) using a c# application.

What I'm doing right now is that I'm creating a fairly large XML file (about 30Mb) that'll contain about 40.000 rows that should be inserted into the database.

From this xml document that I'm passing to the database as a variable I have a Stored procedure that'll read the data from and do appropriate inserts or updates.

**Pseudo c# code:**

```
String xml = xmlWriter.ToString();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_CommitData", connection)
cmd.Variables.AddWithValue("@xml", xml);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while(reader.Read())
{ 
 /* Read return data */
}
```

**Pseudo tsql code:**

```
INSERT INTO DataTable
xmldata.value('@uID','[uniqueidentifier]') AS [uID]
FROM<
@xml.nodes('/data/m/r') [xmldata](xmldata)
```

This approach has worked pretty well for me in the past but now the data appears to be to vast for the approach to work... It takes well over 3 minutes to just commit the data and that's just way to long time. :(

This must be a quite common problem, how do you guys do in a similar scenario?
Do you have any good pointers on how to commit fairly large amount of data with c#. The solution must be thread-safe so I'm not so fancy about a bcp or similar approach.

Kind regards
Drew

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2008? A table valued parameter should help considerably.

Comment: If you are inserting a large amount of data I suggest you look at the `SqlBulkCopy` class

Comment: Are all the 40.000 rows in one transaction? If so, must they be in one transaction?

Comment: Yes, there is about 40.000 rows in one transaction spread over three tables that must be updated as a transaction.

Answer (score 5):

The fastest way to do that is by using a [SqlBulkCopy](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/use-sqlbulkcopy-to-quickly-load-data-from-your-client-to-sql-server), that will use the the bulk loading capabilities of SQL.

The problem with the XML approach is that you first have to convert from your rowset/IEnumerable (what do you have to start with exactly?) to XML, and then push that over the wire. XML is a very bloated format to do that in, that counts when you have a lot of rows as you mention.

The Bulk copy approach will let you stream it row by row without having to materialize the whole thing (into memory or onto disk) so that keeps the memory footprint down.

If the amount of data is very big you might want to load it into a temp table first (so there's no transaction of the real table) and Insert (or [Merge](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/)) that into the real thing.

What do you mean with thread-safe? If you want this operation to not block the client you can start it on a background thread easily. There's no external process or anything you need to start to do this, it runs in-process.

Comment: A comment on SqlBulkCopy is that you need to import to a heap (table without clustered key) and use a table lock in order to optimize performance. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186341(v=sql.105).aspx) and [this discussion thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/932cd26c-53fc-49c0-b082-e7f5f05a9801) for more info.

Comment: Yes, if the DB is busy I'd put it in a temp table first to prevent locking.

Comment: What I ment with thread-safe is that it will be many concurrent calls to this service that'll issue the save to the database. Any of these saves should not block the access to other calls but allow for the service to do concurrent execution of the calls.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input to this problem. I've started looking at the SqlBulkCopy but stoped after a while as I need to have a Stored Procedure that will do the data near logic.
Given that I might many concurrent threads to the service that saves data I can't fill a temporary table with data and later on read stuff from this. 

I then turned my attention to Table Value Parameters and found my answer there. I'm sort of amazed that I haven't tried this before as it worked out very well. In performance figures the save went from about 45 seconds to less than 5 seconds! 

Thank you for pointing my in this direction.